# Trouble with onDraw() method in Android

Tags: android, draw, ondraw

I'm trying to create a Custom View in Android. My View will draw some timelines passed via addTimelines() method. Logcat says there's a NullPointerException executing this code, with debug I've noticed when onDraw() method has called, ArrayList listaTl is empty (its value is null).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class TimelineView extends View 
{
    private Paint p;
    private ArrayList<TimelineGrafica> listaTl;

    public TimelineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        setMinimumHeight(400);
        if(!isInEditMode())
        {init();}
        init();
    }


    public void addTimelines(ArrayList<TimelineGrafica> tls)
    {
        listaTl = tls;
    }

    private void init()
    {
        this.p = new Paint();
    }

    private void disegnaPunta(Canvas c, Paint p, TimelineGrafica t)
    {
        int[] x = new int[3];
        int[] y = new int[3];

        x[0] = t.getTotaleDurata();
        y[0] = t.getCoordinataY() - 20;

        x[1] = t.getTotaleDurata() + 40;
        y[1] = t.getCoordinataY() + (t.getSpessoreTimeline()/2);

        x[2] = t.getTotaleDurata();
        y[2] = t.getCoordinataY() + t.getSpessoreTimeline() + 20;

        c.drawLine(x[0], y[0], x[1], y[1], p);
        c.drawLine(x[1], y[1], x[2], y[2], p);
        c.drawLine(x[0], y[0], x[2], y[2], p);
    }

    private void disegnaRettangolo(Canvas c, Paint p, TimelineGrafica t)
    {
        Rect r = new Rect(t.getCoordinataX(), 
                          t.getCoordinataY(), 
                          t.getTotaleDurata(), 
                          t.getCoordinataY() + 
                          t.getSpessoreTimeline());
        c.drawRect(r, p);
    }

    private void disegnaGrain(Canvas c, Paint p, TimelineGrafica t)
    {
        //Calcolo il 5% di distanza dalla punta
        int numeroFatti = (t.getTotaleDurata() - 
                           (t.getTotaleDurata()*3/100))/
                            t.getDistanzaIntervalli();
        for(int i=0, cX = t.getCoordinataX(); i<numeroFatti; 
                    i++, cX += t.getDistanzaIntervalli())
        {
            c.drawLine(cX, t.getCoordinataY() - 20, cX,
                        t.getCoordinataY() + t.getSpessoreTimeline() + 20, p);
            if(i<=9)
                c.drawText(""+i, cX-3, t.getCoordinataY() + 
                        t.getSpessoreTimeline() + 35, p);
            else
                c.drawText(""+i, cX-5, t.getCoordinataY() + 
                        t.getSpessoreTimeline() + 35, p);               
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if(!listaTl.isEmpty())
            for(TimelineGrafica t : listaTl)
            {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);           
                p.setColor(t.getColor());
                p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE); 
                p.setAntiAlias(true);   
                p.setStrokeWidth(1);
                disegnaGrain(canvas,p,t);
                disegnaRettangolo(canvas,p,t);
                disegnaPunta(canvas,p,t);
            }
    }   
}
```

Here, I call the method to add a new timeline to draw in.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<TimelineGrafica> tl = new ArrayList<TimelineGrafica>();

    this.disegnoTimeline = new TimelineView(this, null);

    PlainTimeLine tlp = ottieniTimeline("Timeline1.txt");
    TimelineGrafica tlpp = new TimelineGrafica(tlp, 10, 30, 20, Color.WHITE); 

    tl.add(tlpp);
    this.disegnoTimeline.addTimelines(tl);  

    setContentView(R.layout.timeline_view);
}
```

The problem is there also if I call method postInvalidate()/invalidate() after addTimelines().

Does anyone know which is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The method postInvalidate() or invalidate(), when it called, the method onDraw() will be recalled
so when you change the TimelineView such as addTimelines(ArrayList), you should refresh itself with postInvalidate() or invalidate()

Comment: Thanks. Which is better for my code? postInvalidate() or invalidate()? I try to call these methods but the problem is the NullPointerException thrown when method onDraw() is called.